# Avoid image stretching

Tags: html, css, image, tags, styles

so I have an image tag on my page that is set to 300px height. When a bigger image is used for it, the image is stretched so it fits and it gets really ugly. Is there a way to just get a part of the image instead, preferably the top 300pxs of it?

Hope I made myself clear, I'm new to this. Thank you!

Comment: You can use CSS to hide parts of the image and control how it is scaled, if that's what you're asking. Please show your HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 4):

I believe

```
overflow:hidden;
```

is what you're looking for. You put that property on a div that surrounds the image, not the image itself. Here's a good resource: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/overflow/

Here's a code sample:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.overflow{
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
img{
    height: 200px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="overflow">
<img src="http://funmozar.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/white-cat.jpg">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You could also want to consider using the max-height and max-width properties. Make sure not to set both height AND width on the image or it will still stretch it to match those parameters.

Answer (score 2):

A possibility is to use the `object-fit` CSS property on the image. For instance, the value `contain` will scale down the image so that its original ratio is maintained; while the value `cover` will crop parts of the image. You can then use the `object-position` property to properly place the scaled down or the croped image.

For more information on these CSS properties and their differents values:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-position

Answer (score 1):

probably the best solution in order to avoid image stretching is to use a div with fixed size (width and height), background-image and use background-size propriety.

**example:**

html:

```
<div id="yourDiv"></div>
```

css:

```
#yourDiv {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url('yourimage.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Please have a look here for other information about background-size: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Comment: Using a background image instead of content images has various implications (on accessibility, printing, etc.). I don’t think you should suggest using a background image when there are several alternatives that use content images.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the image in an element, set fixed dimensions for the container and no dimension settings for the image but `overflow: hidden` on the image. Here’s an example of using small dimensions:

```html
An image:<br>
<img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/100/100" alt="foo"><br>
The same image with just the upper half taken:<br>
<div style="width: 100px; height: 50px; overflow: hidden"><img
   src="http://www.lorempixel.com/100/100" alt="foo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just added this CSS code, and it worked perfectly well. None of the above worked for my case, as my image sizes are different. However, it was very helpful and led me to my solution.

`img { max-width: cover; height: auto; }`